# How to assign values to objects through a variable that is just a reference to them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, methods

I couldn't really word the question less vaguely, but I think you will understand...

I am developing a game engine in Javascript, and the `Scene` object, which is a container of many things, has a method that is supposed to change one array in it, specifically the one holding all the things that can be drawn.

This array is accessed like this:

`scene.internals.draw`

The problem is, it is referenced many times in the method, and I think that the name/path might change. Naturally, I don't want to change every reference to it in the method each time I change the the array's path, so I did this:

`var location = scene.internals.draw;`

Now, the actual method code and the algorithm can stay intact, and if the name/path of the array in the scene changes, I only need to change that one line.

And it works pretty well for the most part. I can `.push(obj)` to it, etc, but at one point, I need to "disect" the array, ie, split it in half, add something, and then put it back together, like this:

```
buff1 = location.slice(0, i); //First slice of the array.
buff2 = location.slice(i, location.length); //Second slice of the array.

//Add something in between those slices.
buff1.push(ob);
location = buff1.concat(buff2); //Problems here!
```

This worked well while `location` was just `scene.internals.draw`, as it changed the array directly. But now, I assign the new value to the local `location` variable, not the desired `scene.internals.draw` one!

Question: **how can I, using the = operator, assign values to "real" objects, instead of the variables that contain references to these objects (like `location`)?**

The obvious solution would be this, at the end of the method:

`scene.internals.draw = location.slice();`

This is OK, the only side effect is that I will have to write the original name twice, and edit it twice, which isn't such a big issue. But, I maybe find myself in other situations where I just might need that functionality, so I'd still like an answer.

Comment: you could rewrite location as a function that handles get and set.

location() would get, and location(arr) would set. not sure if you'll have this working with the = sign

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @CoryDanielson.

Comment: i was thinking something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s2QQK/1/ but Esailija answer is very good. this getter/setter is kind of a nuisance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no assignment by reference in javascript, so you cannot do this. What you are doing is usually mistaken for assignment by reference but it is in fact a copy of a reference value which has implications like this.

You probably have a deeper problem somewhere since you are doing this but I don't wanna get into that.

You could do this:

```
location.splice( 0, location.length ); //Remove all items in the array
location.push.apply( location, buff1.concat(buff2) ); //Push the buffers into the array
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall use this, but doesn't the `.apply` method require an array as the second argument? Shouldn't you be using `.call` instead? Also, why are you changing the context in the first place with these functions?

Comment: Aha! I get it now! `buff.conc...` produces an array... Everything is clear now, thanks.

Comment: @Bane the first argument to `.apply` is the context and the second an is an array that will be the arguments to the function. `buff1.concat(buff2)` will be the array of arguments to `.push` that operates on `.location`

Answer (score 2):

To use your term, there are no "real" objects in Javascript - there are only objects, and the variables that hold *references* to them.

When you assign to `location` you're just creating an *additional* reference to an object.  The system has no knowledge of which "real" object it was, nor of any other variables that may hold references to it.

So when you *reassign* to `location` you're just overwriting that particular reference.  Any other original references to the object will stay pointing just where they were.